# api call with curl -u with token works on Mac and fails on linux

Tags: bash, curl, urlencode

Team,
badly stuck on production for this case, i am unable to make curl call on linux and same works on macbook.
I tried both ways of url construction and both work on mac but not on linux. any hint?
am following this https://community.sonarsource.com/t/using-rest-api-with-user-token/15229

```
#!/bin/bash
# set -v -e -o pipefail
sonar_api() {
    #WORKS ON MAC but fails on LINUX
    # sq_url='https://sonar-sw.company.com/api/'
    # url="${sq_url}qualitygates/project_status?projectKey=aiinfra-pba&pullRequest=${GERRIT_CHANGE_NUMBER}-${GERRIT_PATCHSET_NUMBER}"
    sq_url='https://sonar-sw.company.com/api/qualitygates/project_status'
    url=$sq_url
    curl -vvv -u "${TOKEN}": \
        -G $url \
        --data-urlencode projectKey="pba" \
        --data-urlencode pullRequest="${GERRIT_CHANGE_NUMBER}-${GERRIT_PATCHSET_NUMBER}"
}
sonar_api
```

logs on jenkins SHOWS 404. so that means my URL is messed up on linux? how can i fix my code because exact same work on MAC.

```
{ [5 bytes data]
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 404 
< Server: nginx/1.12.2
< Date: Fri, 24 Mar 2023 19:05:15 GMT
< Content-Type: application/json
< Content-Length: 102
< Connection: keep-alive
< 
{ [102 bytes data]

100   102  100   102    0     0    126      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   126
100   102  100   102    0     0    126      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   126
* Connection #0 to host sonar-sw.company.com left intact
[Pipeline] echo
{"errors":[{"msg"
[Pipeline] }
```

Comment: Can't help with your basic problem, but I did paste your code to https://shellcheck.net and was surprized that it didn't flag your unquoted variables `$sq_url` and `$url`. I guess it is worth trying `"$sq_url"` etc. And unquoted `&` chars in URLs will mess things up (one in your commented out code). ... Ah, and just noticed, are you always running this from inside of `jenkins` in both environments?  I'd recommend adding a tag for that. Also, did you compare `bash` versions between environments? Good luck.

Comment: Macbook is local terminal that works flawless. Only when I push to Jenkins it fails and gives me 404. So somewhere I fee url is messed up or special chars are inserted. 
I will try your suggestions and also move the call Bash to Python and see